# Unable to locally verify issuer's authority?

Tags: linux, ssl, ssl-certificate

We have strange problem where IE7 shows no signs of error, but Firefox and Linux tools do. For example, a wget test one might use in monitoring SSL availability for systems (Public DNS and IP addresses anonymized):

```
wget https://subdomain.website.edu
--2009-09-02 14:11:06--  https://subdomain.website.edu/
Resolving subdomain.website.edu... 192.168.227.87
Connecting to subdomain.website.edu|192.168.227.87|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify subdomain.website.edu's certificate, issued by `/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)05/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to subdomain.website.edu insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
Unable to establish SSL connection
```

"Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority," it says. Is there something wrong with the cert, or something wrong with the local systems verifying the cert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your certificate is probably signed by a certificate that is directly trusted by your browser.  Your web server is not providing the intermediate certificates between a certificate your system trusts and the certificate for the site.

If your web server is apache you probably need to use the **SSLCertificateChainFile** and the appropriate certificate bundle from your [Verisign](https://knowledge.verisign.com/support/ssl-certificates-support/index?page=content&id=AR657) so your web server can provide all the certificates needed to build up the chain of certificates.